# Why wont my custom Arduino-Micro-based board connect over USB?

Tags: usb, arduino-micro

I designed and printed a PCB for my MIDI controller project with a modified Arduino Micro microcontroller essentially built into the design. I swapped out the USB Micro for a USB-C type port (just using the 2.0 protocol). Although I can program the board via ICSP, including getting it to run my Arduino sketches (which I have tested by having it light up the LEDs in a certain pattern, which works as expected), and the fact that it receives power via USB, the problem is that I cannot get the device to connect to my PC over USB - it is not recognized as a USB device, and cannot seem to send or receive data over USB. I'm not sure if I've done something wrong in the design or if I am simply missing something, but could use some advice, as in order to function as intended, the board will need to be able to communicate over USB.

I have tested with various USB-A to USB-C cables and USB-A to Micro cables (tested with other Arduinos) and a Micro to USB-C adapter.

As per various instructions I found online, I connected pull-down resistors of 5.1k Ohms to CC1 and CC2, left SBU1 and SBU2 unconnected as I was planning to use 2.0 protocols to keep things simple (as a related question, can these actually be used to make use of 3.0+ protocols in a design like this with an ATMEGA32U4? Would this be considered better practice in this case and potentially bypass the error?), and wired up D- and D+ as shown in the schematic below; with a EZJZ0V500AA Varistor between each and GND and running through a 4D03WGJ0220T5E Resistor network (which I don't know much about, including whether this type of component has any polarity? I simply tried to follow how the same sort of component was used in the official Arduino Micro schematics) and finally into pins 3 and 4 of the ATMEGA32U4.

This is the original schematic of the board as it was assembled, but as a result of some power issues with this same board which I have since sorted out with help in a separate post [Why wont my custom Arduino-Micro-based board receive power via USB?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/90839/why-wont-my-custom-arduino-micro-based-board-receive-power-via-usb), I had to bypass the 5V regulator and just use VUSB as +5V, so I will put the updated schematic reflecting these changes below the original (I wouldn't think it would affect this issue, but I'm not that experienced and want to err on the side of providing as many details as possible)

Original Schematic:
[image: Original Schematic]

Revised Schematic:
[image: Revised Schematic]

Components:

```
| Designator                                             | Value                   | Component                |
|:--------------------------------------------------------|:-------------------------|:--------------------------|
| C_ARD_1, C_ARD_2, C_ARD_6, C_ARD_9, C_ARD_10, C_ARD_11 | 100n                    | CL05B104KO5NNNC          |
| C_ARD_3, C_ARD_14                                      | 22u                     | RVT22UF16V67RV0017       |
| C_ARD_4, C_ARD_5, C_ARD_7                              | 1uF                     | CL05A105KA5NQNC          |
| C_ARD_12, C_ARD_13                                     | 22pF                    | 0402CG220J500NT          |
| D_ARD_2                                                | CD1206-S01575           | CDSU4148-HF              |
| F1                                                     | MF-MSMF050-2 500mA      | MF-MSMF050-2             |
| J3                                                     | USB_C_Receptacle_USB2.0 | KH-TYPE-C-16P            |
| L1                                                     | green                   | 19-217/GHC-YR1S2/3T      |
| L2                                                     | MH2029-300Y             | BLM21PG300SN1D           |
| ON1                                                    | blue                    | 19-217/BHC-ZL1M2RY/3T    |
| R_ARD_1, R_ARD_2, R_ARD_4, R_ARD_9                     | 10K                     | 0402WGF1002TCE           |
| R_ARD_5, R_ARD_6, R_ARD_7, R_ARD_8                     | 1K                      | 0402WGF1001TCE           |
| R_ARD_10, R_ARD_11                                     | 5.1k                    | 0402WGF5101TCE           |
| RP3                                                    | 22R                     | 4D03WGJ0220T5E           |
| RX1, TX1                                               | yellow                  | 19-213/Y2C-CQ2R2L/3T(CY) |
| T1                                                     | FDN340P/PMV48XP         | PMV48XP                  |
| T2                                                     | PMV48XP                 | PMV48XP                  |
| U1                                                     | ATMEGA32U4-XUMU         | ATMEGA32U4-MU            |
| U2                                                     | NCP1117-5               | NCP1117ST50T3G           |
| U4                                                     | LP2985-33DBVR           | LP2985-33DBVR            |
| Y3                                                     | 16MHz KX-7              | 3225-16.00-10-10-10/A    |
| Z1, Z2                                                 | CG0603MLC-05E           | EZJZ0V500AA              |
```

Comment: Did you try to burn the bootloader over ICSP?

Comment: *"as a side question"* it's probably better than you don't ask that in the same question. I gather you sorted out your power problem and this is now about about data. Or at least I hope that's what's going on. If so, you may want to make that really clear before people start trying to close it as a duplicate. Like before, if you mention that you're testing with a USB-A to USB-C cable, this eliminates any concerns regarding the design or implementation or design surrounding CC1/CC2. They become a non-issue, because they're handled by the cable in that case.

Comment: @chrisl Yes, I have successfully burned the bootloader over ICSP prior to testing it over USB

Comment: @timemage Appreciate the advice, I am fairly new to this platform so wasn't completely sure the best way to go about asking multiple related questions, etc. I did indeed solve the power issues and thought it might confuse things to mention that again here since this seems to be a mostly unrelated issue, but I'll make a note of it in an edit.

Comment: Did you do something like select Arduino Micro and burn the bootloader through ISP? Or did you install use the DFU loader?

Comment: @timemage Yeah in the Arduino 1.8.19 IDE I selected Arduino Micro as the board and burned the bootloader using an Arduino Uno as ISP, and then I also successfully uploaded a sketch through Upload Using Programmer through the ICSP as well. I'm not familiar with the DFU loader but can look into that.

Comment: Is your board works with blinking LED (that's proof the board generally working) or only the USB port not working?

Comment: That was not a recommendation for DFU. Some things to do/measure that you can maybe integrate in the question: Run DRC on the PCB layout if you haven't already.  Measure the UCAP pin to see that 3.3V is there.  Power the board with 5V as though it were connected to USB (don't actually connect it to USB) and measure Measure D+ and D- with a high (15K-50k) valued pulldown after an external reset. See whether or not D+ being pulled up when in the bootloader and that D- is not. If you don't mind the grief involved test with Z1/Z2 removed.

Comment: @hcheung Yes, I was able to successfully upload and run an LED blinking sketch to the board (via ICSP programming) so I believe the board is functioning aside from the USB data transfer.

Comment: Your USB circuitry looks okay, and you are using a USB-2 port which is the correct choice. Have you installed the [USB driver](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/qwiic-pro-micro-usb-c-atmega32u4-hookup-guide/all#windows_driver)?

Comment: @timemage "Not a recommendation for DFU" Understood. Thanks for all the test suggestions. I have been getting a clean read from DRC (though I know from my previous power troubles that that doesn't preclude incorrect footprint selection, so I will double check anything with polarity). Measuring 3.3V at UCAP. As for the final test, do I understand correctly:  remove Z1 and Z2 and effectively replace each with a high value pull-down resistor, burn bootloader to the board, then test (while the board is powered but no sketch running) if D+ is being pulled to a higher voltage while D- is not?

Comment: Sort of, but really suggestion for Z1/Z2 is really separate from the pull-down thing. The idea is that Z1/Z2 are for protection that isn't strictly needed to make it work. So at best they are not interfering. The point of the D+/D- measurement is to see that the chip is actually trying to enumerate at full-speed in the bootloader. The point of the pulling down *while measuring* is that the host that is normally connected (now not connected) usually pulls them weakly toward GND. If you don't do that yourself they may float and give false measurement.

Comment: uploading a sketch with programmer deletes the bootloader

Comment: @hcheung I tried reinstalling the drivers but it didn't seem to help. Thanks for the suggestion and for looking things over

Comment: @timemage Well I was able to do the test today; I added 22k Ohm pulldowns to D+ and D- and measured them while in the bootloader. D+ was reading 3.1V to 3.3V and D- was reading 0V compared to GND. I got the same results with removed Z1 and Z2 and when testing while they were still in place.

Comment: Well, then your chip is enabling USB for full-speed, which is what the caterina bootloader (Arduino Micro bootloader)  does. **If these voltages are making to the host port,** you should, at a minimum get a failure diagnostic in dmesg or device manager or whatever that indicates either a failure to issue USB Set Address or a failure to Get Descriptor, usually the device descriptor. Absence of both would mean something like that's a charge only port, or you have a break in D+ between where you're measuring and the D+ as it goes into the computer/hub.

Comment: One thought that came to my mind, you might want to look into [Atmel DFU driver](http://flysight.ca/wiki/index.php/Installing_DFU_driver).

Comment: @hcheung I took _"not recognized as a USB device"_ to mean that it wasn't enumerating on the USB at all as opposed to enumerated as an "unrecognized device."   If that's correct then it won't matter what drivers are installed, since it would need to enumerate to even know which drivers to consider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I finally found the source of the problem, many thanks to everyone here who helped me narrow things down and kept pointing me in the right direction. After figuring out that D+ and D- were getting pulled appropriately by the chip I decided to desolder the USB port on the board, cut a USB-A 2.0 cable and solder the leads directly to the board and, suddenly, it worked. After this I realized the problem must have been with the USB port on the board and upon comparing the datasheet to my pcb file, I realized that the footprint I used and the one in the datasheet had the pins laid out in a different order.

I feel a bit embarrassed for taking up people's time on such a stupid error I made (and admittedly didn't even provide enough information for anyone to be able to figure out for me, despite all of your patience and helpful advice), but at the same time I am both relieved I figured out the problem and grateful for all the help I got on this post, I'm not sure how long it would have taken me to figure out without your suggestions. I learned a lot about the layout of arduino boards, the purposes of various components in said boards, the importance of double checking footprints, and about better practices for asking for assistance.

As a note on "post etiquette" or whatever you would call it, since everyone provided assistance in comments, I didn't see a way to close the post without answering my own question (I am new to posting here), so I hope that is an acceptable way to do so.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to answer your own question and mark it as accepted. You might want to read some pages of the [help] to learn more.